# Is there a way for formatting the `var_dump` or `print_r`'s data?

Tags: php

Is there a way for formatting the `var_dump` or `print_r`'s data?

We often use `var_dump` and `print_r` for check a array or object.

but that's very complex data. there is no level. What a mass.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the text :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 190 [ipv4s] => Array ( ) [physical_server_buy_record] => stdClass Object ( [is_using] => [desc] => [create_time] => 2018-07-25T04:26:09.942404Z [expire_time] => 2018-07-25T04:26:09.942404Z ) [server_status] => 今天过期 [name] => SE02-B24 [desc] => [cpu] => Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5 [ram] => Supermicro DDR4___16 [disk] => Intel SSD___240 [price] => 1000.00 [pay_time] => 2018-07-25T12:26:09.841842+08:00 [expire_time] => 2018-07-26T12:11:45.841842+08:00 [ipmi_addr] => 172.16.30.216 [ipmi_account_and_pwd] => [customer_desc] => [whmcs_tblhosting_id] => [ctime] => 2018-07-02T05:11:43.176443+08:00 [uptime] => 2018-07-25T12:26:09.995883+08:00 [physical_server_model] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8 .....
```

So, is there a way for formatting this type data?

such as, if there is a complex json data, we can paste to json.cn, there will format it.

Comment: you can go to source page and view it, most of the time I view it like this,

Comment: or try var_export

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);`

Comment: Or you can also add at the start of PHP file. `<pre><?php`

Comment: I highly recommend getting chrome extension var_masterpiece. Your life will improve by at least 15%. Also, get JSON formatter.

Comment: @SuperKevin What do you mean of JSON formatter?

Comment: Those are chrome plugins that can be useful when you output to the browser.